# How do I go from $E[Z_{n+1}\mid {\mathcal {F}}_{n}] = Z_n,\; n \in \mathbb N$ to $E[Z_{n}|{\mathcal {F}}_{k}]=Z_k,\;k<n$ using the tower rule?

Tags: martingales

How do I go from $E[Z_{n+1}\mid {\mathcal {F}}_{n}] = Z_n,\; n \in \mathbb N$ to $E[Z_{n}|{\mathcal {F}}_{k}]=Z_k,\;k<n$ using the tower rule?

Comment: You're missing some quantifiers in your first equation. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Jose Avilez, I added the quantifiers now. I realize my understanding of the tower rule is inadequate. I only knew it as E(E(X|Y)) = E(X) but it seems the following is also correct E(E(X|Z)|Y) = E(X|Y).

Answer (score 1):

$E[Z_{n+1}|F_n] = Z_n$ holds when $Z_n$ is a martingale w.r.t. filtration $F_n$.
Since we want to prove $E[Z_n|F_k] = Z_k$ for some $k < n$, you need to use the tower rule:
\begin{equation}
E[E[Y|X]|W] = E[Y|W]
\end{equation}

Starting with $n-1$, we have $E[Z_n|F_{n-1}] = Z_{n-1}$ by the martingale property. Taking the conditional expectation of both sides given $F_{n-2}$ and evoking the tower rule, we have
\begin{equation}
E[E[Z_n|F_{n-1}]|F_{n-2}] = E[Z_{n-1}|F_{n-2}]
\implies E[Z_n|F_{n-2}] = E[Z_{n-1}|F_{n-2}]
\end{equation}

But we have $E[Z_{n-1}|F_{n-2}] = Z_{n-2}$ by the martingale property, so
\begin{equation}
E[Z_n|F_{n-2}] = E[Z_{n-1}|F_{n-2}] \implies E[Z_n|F_{n-2}] = Z_{n-2}
\end{equation}

This iterative process continues when you take $n-2, n-3, \cdots, k$ until you get
$E[Z_n|F_k] = Z_k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Isn't it supposed to say E[E[Y|X]|W] = E[Y|W] instead?

Comment: Yep @kahan -- Everything else in the proof should still hold though!

Comment: Yeah the proof is dope, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks again!